# How to show custom message of route not found in expressjs?

Tags: node.js, express, express-router

**I used this code at the bottom of app.js**

```
app.use(function (req, res) {
   res.send('Route Not Found');
})
```

But it executes in every request. I want to execute it only when route is not found.

Answer (score 2):

This works fine. Make sure to place `app.get('*' ...` **at the end of each file** with routes if you are including external routes files.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get('/', function(req, res){
        res.status(200).send('GET /')
})

app.get('/a', function(req, res){
        res.status(200).send('GET /a')
})

app.get('*', function(req, res){
        res.status(404).send('404')
})

app.listen(3000)
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your routes handler before :

```
app.get("/a", require("./controllers/handler1.js"); // catch get route on a
app.get("/b", require("./controllers/handler2.js"); // catch get route on b
app.post("/a", require("./controllers/handler1.js"); // catch post route on a

// error handler, if no route has been caught
app.get("/*", function(req, res){ res.send("404 not found"); res.end();});
app.post("/*", function(req, res){ res.send("404 not found"); res.end();});
```

Comment: same result. when the request comes to route "/a" then it found in ''/*". both are executed

Comment: cuz your /a handler, here require("./controllers/handler1.js"); has to stop the flow with :

res.status(200).json({key: "value"}); or res.send("erter"); if you don't stop the flow, it pass through the other "matching" middleware until the end.